# Simple INSERT with Dapper on Oracle

Tags: oracle

I would like to use Dapper to have db agnostic code used for e.g. PostgreSQL and Oracle with as little db flavored code as possible. This INSERT code is running without problems for SQL-server and PostgreSQL:

```
var item = new Item { Name = "Test Name", Number = "Test Number" };
await Connection.ExecuteAsync(@"INSERT INTO Table (Name, Number) VALUES (@Name, @Number);", item);
```

On Oracle (version 11 xe), I get an ORA-00936: missing expression.

Do I need tailoring using DynamicParameters or the likes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `:` in front of query parameters instead of `@`. It's an Oracle thing.

```cs
var item = new Item { Name = "Test Name", Number = "Test Number" };
await Connection.ExecuteAsync(@"INSERT INTO Table (Name, Number) VALUES (:Name, :Number)", item);
```

Comment: I've tried, but then I get an `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException : ORA-00911: invalid character`.

Comment: Ah, that was because of my `;` at the end. Now it works. Thanx.

Comment: @Per Erik Gransøe: I didn't notice that ;-). I've removed it from my answer as well.